# How do we call a function each time an api end-point is called in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

In my Django server, there is an rest api through which we are saving the values in the database. If the name exists in the database then I update the value or else will create a new value and name. The code for the function is given below:

```
def getIgnitionData():
    name_list =[]
    value_list =[]
    cursor = connections['ignition'].cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM MDA_table')
    value = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.execute('SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = \'MDA_table\'')
    name = cursor.fetchall()

    for i in name:
        name_list.append(str(i[0]))


    for row in value:
        for j in row:
            value_list.append(str(j))

    cursor.close()
    print name_list
    print value

    #Here we will check to see if the variable exists. If so, update the value. If not,
    #then create a new variable.
    for k in range(0,len(name_list)):
        if (Ignition.objects.filter(name = name_list[k]).exists()):
            Ignition.objects.filter(name=name_list[k]).update(value = value_list[k])
        else:
            Ignition.objects.create(name=name_list[k], value=value_list[k])
```

The view_api.py is as follows:

```
class IgnitionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows to view variables from the ignition database.
    """
    serializer_class = IgnitionSerializer
    #queryset = ignition.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [HasGroupPermission]
    required_groups = {
        'GET': ['Admin', 'Facility', 'Operator'],
        'PUT': [],
        'POST': [],
    }
    ignition.getIgnitionData() # This is where we are calling the function 
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Ignition.objects.all()
```

The code works well when I run the get request for the first time from the browser, but then if I update the values in the database without restarting the server then it doesn't even print the name_list (which means it doesn't call the code). If I restart the server and access the end point, then it does fetch the updated values. This is not practical though.

I wanted that whenever I call the api endpoint it fetches the updated values from the database so that I don't have to restart the server every time. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fix your  indatation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override [`dispatch()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.dispatch) method which is calling each time your view is using:

```
class IgnitionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows to view variables from the ignition database.
    """
    serializer_class = IgnitionSerializer
    #queryset = ignition.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [HasGroupPermission]
    required_groups = {
        'GET': ['Admin', 'Facility', 'Operator'],
        'PUT': [],
        'POST': [],
    }

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ignition.getIgnitionData() # This is where we are calling the function 
        return super(IgnitionViewSet, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Ignition.objects.all()
```

Comment: When I added the dispatch I am getting this error: TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given), What should I add in super(). Thanks.

Comment: @M.Shaikh this is because you are using Python2. In your case it should be `return super(IgnitionViewSet, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)`